# Pipe does not pass all of the data

Tags: python

I am trying to replicate what happens on the stdout of a `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)` object when the spawned command becomes unresponsive and read() calls start to block. Here's the desired behavior: create a pipe, write to the pipe, read from the pipe, once all of the data has been read, any further reads will block. I have confirmed this works in the REPL:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.pipe()
(3, 4)
>>> a = os.fdopen(3)
>>> b = os.fdopen(4, 'w')
>>> b.write("line 1\n"
...         "line 2\n"
...         "line 3\n"
...         "line 4\n"
...         "line 5\n")
>>> b.flush()
>>> a.readline()
'line 1\n'
>>> a.readline() 
'line 2\n'
>>> a.readline()
'line 3\n'
>>> a.readline()
'line 4\n'
>>> a.readline()
'line 5\n'
>>> a.readline()
    ## hangs here forever...
```

However, seemingly the same type of thing in the code below only produces the first line of output before the rest of the reads are blocked. What am I doing wrong??

**Code:**

```
import os
import select


class Stuck():
    def __init__(self):
        pipe_readfd, pipe_writefd = os.pipe() 
        self.output = os.fdopen(pipe_readfd, 'r') 

        self.writer = os.fdopen(pipe_writefd, 'w')
        self.writer.write('output line 1\n'
                          'output line 2\n'
                          'output line 3\n'
                          'output line 4\n'
                          'output line 5\n')
        self.writer.flush()


class Runner():
    def run(self, timeout=3):
            stuck = Stuck()
            opendescriptors = [stuck.output]
            timeout_counter = 0 
            while opendescriptors:
                pending = select.select(opendescriptors, [], [], 1)[0]
                if not pending:
                    timeout_counter += 1
                    if timeout_counter >= timeout:
                        print "*** STUCK FOR OVER {} SECONDS ***\n".format(timeout)
                        return False
                else:
                    timeout_counter = 0 
                    for fd in pending:
                        line = fd.readline()
                        if line == '': 
                            opendescriptors.remove(fd)
                        else:
                            print line


def test():
    runner = Runner()
    runner.run() 
    print "Expecting five lines of output followed by TIMEOUT"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

**Produces this:**

```
output line 1

*** STUCK FOR OVER 3 SECONDS ***

Expecting five lines of output followed by TIMEOUT
```

Comment: select is very OS-centric.  Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on OS X and Linux. The 'select' aspect seems to be consistent, I have no reason to think it's misbehaving, if the read is going to be blocked, select does not return the descriptor. I think the issue is more with why the reads start blocking after only the first line, instead of after all five lines...

Comment: If the flush() is changed to a close(), I get all five lines of output. What's happening to the other four if the writing end of the pipe is not closed?

Comment: After further testing, I agree that 'select' is suspect. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would not use python select with file handles in a cross platform app.  select works great for network stuff, but the file handling can be a challenge.  If I had a reasonable number of files to monitor I would use a threading based solution.  There are a few solutions in this vein here on SO.

Comment: Agreed. 
But as it turns out, I have replaced readline() with os.read(), and I am getting the result I was expecting. Thanks for your help narrowing down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `readline()` does a lot of stuff under the hood that does not play nice with `select()`. Replacing `readline()` with `os.read()`  leads to correct behavior. Using threads instead of `select()` is another route.